# VC-based risk bounds for classifiers on finite set

Tags: st.statistics, machine-learning, learning-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set and let $\emptyset\neq \mathcal{H}\subseteq \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathcal{X}}$.  Let $\{(X_n,L_n)\}_{n=1}^N$ be i.i.d. random variables on $X\times \{0,1\}$ with law $\mathbb{P}$.  Without knowing more of $\mathcal{H}$, what is the best risk-bounds available via VC-dimension or Rademacher-complexity theory on the *true risk*
$$
\sup_{h\in \mathcal{H}}\,\mathbb{E}_{(X,L)\sim \mathbb{P}}[I(h(x)=L)] - \frac1{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\, I(h(X_n)=L_n)?
$$

Comment: The displayed expression is a random variable, say $Z_n$. What do you then mean by a  best risk-bound on $Z_n$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Ah, PAC-type bounds.  Something like, for each $\delta \in (0,1]$ the above quantity is less that ... +(some term likely of the form $\log(1/\delta)$ ) holds with probability at-least $1-\delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\HH{\mathcal H}\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$Let
\begin{equation}
    D_N:=\sup_{h\in\HH}\Big(E\,I(h(X)=L) - \frac1{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\, I(h(X_n)=L_n)\Big).
\end{equation}

It was shown in (the proof of) [Long's main result, 1999](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1007666507971) (which he ascribed to Talagrand) that
\begin{equation}
    P(|D_N|>\ep)\le\exp\Big(d_\HH-cN\ep^2)
\end{equation}
for some real $c>0$, all $N$, and all real $\ep>0$, where $d_\HH$ is the VC dimension of $\HH$.

Similar results, but in terms of certain covering numbers for $\HH$ rather than the VC dimension, were obtained by [Talagrand, 1994](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-22/issue-1/Sharper-Bounds-for-Gaussian-and-Empirical-Processes/10.1214/aop/1176988847.full).

At least as recently as in October 2019, these results by Talagrand and Long still [seemed to be the state of the art](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-47/issue-5/Exact-lower-bounds-for-the-agnostic-probably-approximately-correct-PAC/10.1214/18-AOS1766.full).

Comment: Wow this is extremely interesting!  Thank you Iosif and doubly-so for the lower-bound paper, optimality was my next question! :)